# Error catching in stacks

Tags: data-structures, error-handling, stack

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;



public class InfixExpressionEvaluator {
// Tokenizer to break up our input into tokens
StreamTokenizer tokenizer;

// Stacks for operators (for converting to postfix) and operands (for
// evaluating)
StackInterface<Character> operatorStack;
StackInterface<Double> operandStack;

//counts brackets
int Bracket1=0, Bracket2=0, count = 0;

/**
 * Initializes the evaluator to read an infix expression from an input
 * stream.
 * @param input the input stream from which to read the expression
 */
public InfixExpressionEvaluator(InputStream input) {
    // Initialize the tokenizer to read from the given InputStream
    tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(input)));

    // StreamTokenizer likes to consider - and / to have special 
meaning.
    // Tell it that these are regular characters, so that they can be 
parsed
    // as operators
    tokenizer.ordinaryChar('-');
    tokenizer.ordinaryChar('/');

    // Allow the tokenizer to recognize end-of-line, which marks the 
end of
    // the expression
    tokenizer.eolIsSignificant(true);

    // Initialize the stacks
    operatorStack = new ArrayStack<Character>();
    operandStack = new ArrayStack<Double>();
}

/**
 * Parses and evaluates the expression read from the provided input 
stream,
 * then returns the resulting value
 * @return the value of the infix expression that was parsed
 */
public Double evaluate() throws ExpressionError {
    // Get the first token. If an IO exception occurs, replace it with 
a
    // runtime exception, causing an immediate crash.
    try {
        tokenizer.nextToken();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    boolean preNum = false, preOp = false;
    boolean preOpenbracket = false, preClosebracket = false;
    int Bracket1 = 0, Bracket2 = 0, count = 0;

    // Continue processing tokens until we find end-of-line
    while (tokenizer.ttype != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL) {
        // Consider possible token type
        switch (tokenizer.ttype) {
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                // Expression error handling
                if ((preNum == true) && (count > 0)) {
                    throw new ExpressionError("Two operands in a row");
                }
                if ((preClosebracket == true) && (count > 0)) {
                    throw new ExpressionError("A close bracket cannot 
be followed by a number");
                }

                // If the token is a number, process it as a double-
valued
                // operand
                processOperand((double) tokenizer.nval);
                preOp = false;
                preNum = true;
                preOpenbracket = false;
                preClosebracket = false;
               break;
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
            case '^':
                // check for errror in input
                if (count == 0) {
                    throw new ExpressionError("Leading off with 
 operator is illegal");
                }
                if ((preOp == true) && (count > 0)) {
                    throw new ExpressionError("Two operators in a 
row");
                }
                if ((preOpenbracket == true) && (count > 0)) {
                    throw new ExpressionError("An open bracket cannot 
be followed by an operator");
                }

                // If the token is any of the above characters, process 
  it
                // is an operator
                processOperator((char) tokenizer.ttype);
                preOp = true;
                preNum = false;
                preOpenbracket = false;
                preClosebracket = false;
                break;
            case '(':
            case '[':
                // Expression error handling
                if ((preNum == true) && (count > 0)) {
                    throw new ExpressionError("An open bracket cannot 
be preceded by a number");
                }
                // If the token is open bracket, process it as such. 
Forms
                // of bracket are interchangeable but must nest 
properly.
                processOpenBracket((char) tokenizer.ttype);

                preOp = false;
                preNum = false;
                preOpenbracket = true;
                preClosebracket = false;
                Bracket1++;
                break;
            case ')':
            case ']':
                 // Expression error handling
                if ((preOp == true) && (count > 0)) {
                    throw new ExpressionError("A close bracket cannot 
 be preceded by a operator");
                }

                // If the token is close bracket, process it as such. 
Forms
                // of bracket are interchangeable but must nest 
properly.
                processCloseBracket((char) tokenizer.ttype);

                preOp = false;
                preNum = false;
                preOpenbracket = false;
                preClosebracket = true;
                Bracket2++;
                break;
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                // If the token is a "word", throw an expression error
                throw new ExpressionError("Unrecognized token: "
                        + tokenizer.sval);
            default:
                // If the token is any other type or value, throw an
                // expression error
                throw new ExpressionError("Unrecognized token: "
                        + String.valueOf((char) tokenizer.ttype));
        }
        count++;

        // Read the next token, again converting any potential IO 
exception
        try {
            tokenizer.nextToken();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    // Almost done now, but we may have to process remaining operators 
  in
    // the operators stack
    processRemainingOperators();

    if (Bracket1 != Bracket2) {
        throw new ExpressionError("\nNot the same number of bracket");
    }

    // Return the result of the evaluation - 
    return operandStack.pop();
}


void processOperand(double operand) {
//push operand
    operandStack.push(operand);
}


void processOperator(char operator) {
    // Precedence order: ^*/ level 2, +- level 1, ( and [ has lowest 
level 0
    while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && hasPrecedence(operator, 
operatorStack.peek())) {

        // perform step 1a,1b,1c,1d
        operandStack.push(applyOp(operatorStack.pop(), 
operandStack.pop(), operandStack.pop()));
    }
    // Step 2: thisOp has more precedence than one on top of 
operatorStack, push it
    operatorStack.push(operator);
}

// Returns true if 'op2' has higher or same precedence as 'op1',
// otherwise returns false.
public static boolean hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
{
    if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')' || op2 == '[' || op2 == ']')
        return false;
    if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/' || op1 == '^') && (op2 == '+' || op2 
== '-'))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

void processOpenBracket(char openBracket) {
    operatorStack.push(openBracket);
}


void processCloseBracket(char closeBracket) {
    //Declare variables
    char operator='0';
    double a=0, b=0, c=0;
    boolean correct = true;

    //check for error before loop
    if (operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ExpressionError("Brackets/parenthasis are uneven");
    } 
    if (operatorStack.peek()== '(' || operatorStack.peek()=='[') {
        throw new ExpressionError("There was an empty set of brackets 
 or unneeded use of brackets");
    }
    if (operandStack.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ExpressionError("Too many operators");
    }

    //loop through stacks and pop off operators and operands
    while (correct) {
        operator = operatorStack.pop();
        b = operandStack.pop();
        a = operandStack.pop();

        //check  to see if next one is bracket
        if (operatorStack.peek() == '(' || operatorStack.peek() == '[') 
 { 
            correct = false;
        }
    } 

    //check for errors
    if (closeBracket == ')' && !operatorStack.isEmpty() && 
operatorStack.peek() != '(') {
        throw new ExpressionError("Parenthesis do not match");
    }
    if (closeBracket == ']' && !operatorStack.isEmpty() && 
operatorStack.peek() != '[') {
        throw new ExpressionError("Brackets do not match");
    }

    //calculate result and push it onto the stack, pop off bracket
    c = applyOp(operator, b, a);
    operandStack.push(c);
    operatorStack.pop();
}

public static double applyOp(char op, double b, double a)
{
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '^':
            return pow(a,b);
        case '/':
        //check for division by zero
        if (b == 0)
            throw new ExpressionError("No division by zero");
        return a / b;
    }
    return 0;
 }

 /**
 * This method is called when the evaluator encounters the end of an
 * expression. It manipulates operatorStack and/or operandStack to 
 process
 * the operators that remain on the stack, according to the Infix-to-
 Postfix
 * and Postfix-evaluation algorithms.
 */
void processRemainingOperators() {
    //error check
    double a;
    if (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
        if (operatorStack.peek()=='(' || operatorStack.peek()=='[') {
            throw new ExpressionError("Uneven number of parenthesis");
        }

        //check for expression ending with operator
        a=operandStack.pop();
        if (operandStack.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ExpressionError("You can not end with an 
operator");
        }
        operandStack.push(a);

    }

    //process the remaining operators and answer is placed in the stack 
alone
    while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
        operandStack.push(applyOp(operatorStack.pop(), 
operandStack.pop(), operandStack.pop()));
    }
}


/**
 * Creates an InfixExpressionEvaluator object to read from System.in, 
then
 * evaluates its input and prints the result.
 * @param args not used
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("\nInfix expression:");
    InfixExpressionEvaluator evaluator =
                    new InfixExpressionEvaluator(System.in);
    Double value = null;
    try {
        value = evaluator.evaluate();
    } catch (ExpressionError e) {
        System.out.println("ExpressionError: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    if (value != null) {
        System.out.println(value);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Evaluator returned null");
    }
}

}
```

So for this program we're supposed to use implement two stacks to do simple arithmetic. If entered correctly, the program works, but when I try to do error catching it doesn't work. I tried using counter variables for counting number of parenthesis, brackets but it didn't work. Here are some cases that didn't work:

```
2^(2+3*4)

2*14.5+6/5-(5*8-5/9)

10000 * [1+.20/12]^(12*4)

(4+3*2    (error catch here. program should report error because there 
is no closed parenthesis)
```

and many more... any ideas?

Comment: Brackets without optimization usually define their own expression trees. Try doing that, maybe - this might require custom cutoff definitions (other than `eof`, I mean) for nested expressions, though.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Could you elaborate a little more on what you mean by that?

Comment: What I was referring to is once you encounter a bracket you would initialize another nested `InfixExpressionEvaluator` that would stop on encountering a closing bracket of same kind rather than on `eof`. When it nests itself like that, it's sort of easier to track whether brackets are balanced properly, because nested evaluator would throw an exception of which you could have more context on.